# Fatal disk error on datanode DataNode failed volumes:

Tags: hadoop

i am getting the following log on my namenode and its removing my datanode from execution

```
2013-02-08 03:25:54,345 WARN  namenode.NameNode (NameNodeRpcServer.java:errorReport(825)) - Fatal disk error on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50010: DataNode failed volumes:/home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current;
2013-02-08 03:25:54,349 INFO  net.NetworkTopology (NetworkTopology.java:remove(367)) - Removing a node: /default-rack/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50010
```

Can anyone suggest how to rectify this ?

Data Node Logs:

```
2013-02-08 03:25:54,718 WARN datanode.DataNode (FSDataset.java:checkDirs(871)) - Removing failed volume /home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current:   
    org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: can not create directory: /home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current/BP-876979163-137.132.153.125-13602411944‌​23/current/finalized 
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:87)
```

Comment: What does the Data node logs for the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server say?

Comment: the logs in datanode is below.                                      2013-02-08 03:25:54,718 WARN  datanode.DataNode (FSDataset.java:checkDirs(871)) - Removing failed volume /home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: can not create directory: /home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current/BP-876979163-137.132.153.125-1360241194423/current/finalized
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:87)

Answer (score 0):

Things that make be causing this error message:

- Does the directory / path to the directory exist
- Does the user under which the datanode process is running, have permissions to create / write to this directory

  /home/srikmvm/hadoop-0.23.0/tmp/current/BP-876979163-137.132.153.125-13602411944‌​23/current/finalized